# Spring Security Upgrade breaks security authorize tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I upgraded my Spring app a while back,  but some testing found a page that is breaking.  I am using Spring Core 4.2.5.RELEASE,  and Security 3.2.0.RELEASE.  I have this .jsp fragment:

```
<% boolean userIsLocked = false; %>
```

then this authorize tag:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated() && !userIsLocked">
```

I am getting a 500 error with this root cause:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 21): Property or field 'userIsLocked' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?
```

This used to work.  But I did upgrade a while ago, but have not tested this page since then, so I assume it has something to do with that.

Comment: Can you even login when user (account) is locked?

Comment: No,  same error.